# Pong Game - The ball movement is not smooth when storing position with float

Tags: game-physics, game-development, webassembly, assemblyscript

I am developing a `pong-like` game using [Wasm4](https://wasm4.org/). I have important entities with different approaches for movement, one is the `Player` which is the paddle and the other is the `Ball`, the mainly difference between the two of them are that the Player moves through the user input, storing it's position using *i32* and the Ball has a `speed` and a `direction` vector which updates it's position every frame.

---

The Ball code

```js
export class Ball extends Entity {
   private position: Position<f32> = new Position<f32>();
   private speed: u8 = 2;
   
   public spawn(x: i32, y: i32): void {
    this.position.x = x;
    this.position.y = y;

    let angle = <f32>randomInRangeFloat(30, 150);
    angle = angle * <f32>(Math.PI / 180);

    this.direction.x = <f32>Math.cos(angle);
    this.direction.y = <f32>Math.sin(angle);
  }

  public update(): Ball {
    this.position.x += this.direction.x * this.speed;
    this.position.y += this.direction.y * this.speed;

    // ...
  }

  public draw(): Ball {
    w4.oval(
      <i32>this.position.x,
      <i32>this.position.y,
      this.size,
      this.size
    );
  }
}
```

---

The thing is, when I use the position with `f32` the movement seems pretty *glitchy* but accurate with the direction given in the spawn, but when I change the position to `i32` the movement is very smooth, but the movement is very odd, it won't work with smaller speeds for instance.

I am fairly new to game development so I don't know if there's a problem in my formula or I should be adding another element somewhere.

Hope someone can help me. (If I didn't provided enough information please request me and I'll enhance the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like you are not doing anything wrong, but you are starting to hit one of the deeper subjects in game development: anti-aliasing.

The Wikipedia article for [rasterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation) has a nice [animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation#/media/File:Line_pixel_subpixel_aa.gif) about it. If this is the kind of thing that happens to your game, then it may be the time to introduce anti-aliasing filters. Unfortunately, I am not an expert in game development, so I can just direct you to the simplest algorithms, like [Bresenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). The Wikipedia article should also rabbit-hole you into this vast field.

And, of course, [Handmade Hero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imW4sX3vVwY) is always a nice learning resource.